# Is there a mySQL procedure that can merge duplicate rows of data into one, then allow me to manipulate that data as if it were one row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to come up with a stored procedure that takes multiple rows that are exactly identical, and combines them into one row while summing one column, which can then be run through more stored procedures based on the sum of that one column.

I've tried a `GROUP BY` statement, but that doesn't actually group the rows together, because if I run the table through another procedure it performs actions as if each row were not combined. Performing a `SELECT * FROM mytable` query shows that each row was not actually combined into one.

Is there any way to permanently combine multiple rows into one singular row?

To start, I've got a table like this:

```
+-------+-----+--------+---------+------+-----+-----------+
| RowID | pID |  Name  |  Date   | Code | QTY | Purchased |
+-------+-----+--------+---------+------+-----+-----------+
|     1 |   1 | bob    | 9/29/20 |  123 |   1 |           |
|     2 |   1 | bob    | 8/10/20 |  456 |   1 |           |
|     3 |   2 | rob    | 9/15/20 |  123 |   1 |           |
|     4 |   2 | rob    | 9/15/20 |  123 |   1 |           |
|     5 |   2 | rob    | 9/15/20 |  123 |   1 |           |
|     6 |   2 | rob    | 9/15/20 |  123 |   1 |           |
|     7 |   2 | rob    | 9/15/20 |  123 |   1 |           |
|     8 |   3 | john   | 7/12/20 |  987 |   1 |           |
|     9 |   3 | john   | 7/12/20 |  987 |   1 |           |
|    10 |   4 | george | 9/12/20 |  684 |   1 |           |
|    11 |   5 | paul   | 2/2/20  |  454 |   1 |           |
|    12 |   6 | amy    | 1/12/20 |  252 |   1 |           |
|    13 |   7 | susan  | 5/30/20 |  131 |   1 |           |
|    14 |   7 | susan  | 6/6/20  |  252 |   1 |           |
|    15 |   7 | susan  | 5/30/20 |  131 |   1 |           |
+-------+-----+--------+---------+------+-----+-----------+
```

By the end, i'd like to have a table like this:

```
+-------+-----+--------+---------+------+-----+-----------+
| RowID | pID |  Name  |  Date   | Code | QTY | Purchased |
+-------+-----+--------+---------+------+-----+-----------+
|     1 |   1 | bob    | 9/29/20 |  123 |   1 |           |
|     2 |   1 | bob    | 8/10/20 |  456 |   1 |           |
|     3 |   2 | rob    | 9/15/20 |  123 |   5 |           |
|     4 |   3 | john   | 7/12/20 |  987 |   2 |           |
|     5 |   4 | george | 9/12/20 |  684 |   1 |           |
|     6 |   5 | paul   | 2/2/20  |  454 |   1 |           |
|     7 |   6 | amy    | 1/12/20 |  252 |   1 |           |
|     8 |   7 | susan  | 5/30/20 |  131 |   2 |           |
|     9 |   7 | susan  | 6/6/20  |  252 |   1 |           |
+-------+-----+--------+---------+------+-----+-----------+
```

Where exactly identical rows are combined into one row, and the QTY field is summed, that I can then add purchases to, or make deductions from the quantity as a total. Using GROUP BY statements can achieve this, but when I go to alter the quantity or add purchases to each person, it treats it like the first table, as if nothing was actually grouped.

Comment: 'Is there any way to permanently combine multiple rows into one singular row?'  - you would have to create a new table based on your grouped by query. Are you sure you want to lose the data from your original table?

Comment: Grouping is about changing the *result* of your query. Not the original data. Do you need your `RowID` column to be as you put it - namely as an uninterrupted series of integers? Could it not be a sequence number within the combination of  `pID` and `date` ?

Comment: Please provide CREATE TABLE statement for your table.

Answer (score 0):

So you have this table:

```
| RowID | pID |  Name  |  Date   | Code | QTY | Purchased |
+-------+-----+--------+---------+------+-----+-----------+
|     1 |   1 | bob    | 9/29/20 |  123 |   1 |           |
|     2 |   1 | bob    | 8/10/20 |  456 |   1 |           |
|     3 |   2 | rob    | 9/15/20 |  123 |   1 |           |
|     4 |   2 | rob    | 9/15/20 |  123 |   1 |           |
|     5 |   2 | rob    | 9/15/20 |  123 |   1 |           |
|     6 |   2 | rob    | 9/15/20 |  123 |   1 |           |
|     7 |   2 | rob    | 9/15/20 |  123 |   1 |           |
|     8 |   3 | john   | 7/12/20 |  987 |   1 |           |
|     9 |   3 | john   | 7/12/20 |  987 |   1 |           |
|    10 |   4 | george | 9/12/20 |  684 |   1 |           |
|    11 |   5 | paul   | 2/2/20  |  454 |   1 |           |
|    12 |   6 | amy    | 1/12/20 |  252 |   1 |           |
|    13 |   7 | susan  | 5/30/20 |  131 |   1 |           |
|    14 |   7 | susan  | 6/6/20  |  252 |   1 |           |
|    15 |   7 | susan  | 5/30/20 |  131 |   1 |           |
```

The best way, as has been suggested, is to create a new table with the content of your query, then to rename the old table, and the new table to the original table's name, to check if everything is all right, and to drop the original table if yes.

```
CREATE TABLE indata_new AS
WITH grp AS (
  SELECT
    MIN(rowid) AS orowid
  , pid
  , name
  , MAX(date) AS date
  , code
  , SUM(qty) AS qty
  FROM indata
  GROUP BY
    pid
  , name
  , code
)
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY orowid ASC) AS rowid
, *
FROM grp;

ALTER TABLE indata RENAME TO indata_old;
ALTER TABLE indata_new RENAME TO indata;
-- if "indata" now contains the data you want ...
SELECT * FROM indata;
-- out  rowid | orowid | pid |  name  |    date    | code | qty 
-- out -------+--------+-----+--------+------------+------+-----
-- out      1 |      1 |   1 | bob    | 2020-09-29 |  123 |   1
-- out      2 |      2 |   1 | bob    | 2020-08-10 |  456 |   1
-- out      3 |      3 |   2 | rob    | 2020-09-15 |  123 |   5
-- out      4 |      8 |   3 | john   | 2020-07-12 |  987 |   2
-- out      5 |     10 |   4 | george | 2020-09-12 |  684 |   1
-- out      6 |     11 |   5 | paul   | 2020-02-02 |  454 |   1
-- out      7 |     12 |   6 | amy    | 2020-01-12 |  252 |   1
-- out      8 |     13 |   7 | susan  | 2020-05-30 |  131 |   2
-- out      9 |     14 |   7 | susan  | 2020-06-06 |  252 |   1

-- you can ...
DROP TABLE indata_old;
```